# Dynamic Dropdown options based on Text box autocomplete in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, dynamic, dropdown

I am using Laravel, Jquery & MaterializeCSS. My Requirement is to populate drop down options in form based on a text input auto-complete. I am using one source for text autocomplete and another source to fill dropdown. Its a multi select. After the inoput field is populated from autocomplete the dropdown is not populating. If we clock on dropdown its not showing anything, but when I select the default one, its showing value shown as in the image which is coming from the source.

[After autocpmplete of text field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jh1I4.png)

[When selected option then its showing the city value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAcpz.png)

Please help in fixing this issue. Here is my code.

HTML:

```
   <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l4">
    {!! Form::label('company_w', 'Company') !!}
    {!! Form::text('company_w', null, ['class' => 'validate']) !!}
   <input id="company_id" name="company_id" type="hidden" />
</div>

<div class="input-field col s12 m6 l4">

        <select id="city_id" name="city_id" multiple>
        <option value="">--</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

JScript:

```
        $(function() {
        $("#company_w").autocomplete({
            source: "companies/autocompletecompanies",
            minLength: 3,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $('#company_w').val(ui.item.value);
                $('#company_id').val(ui.item.id);

                $.get("/companies/autocompletecompanycities",
                        {company_id: ui.item.id},
                        function (data, status) {

                            var model = $('#city_id');
                            model.empty();
                            $.each(data, function (index, element) {
                                model.append("<option value='"+ element.id +"'>" + element.name + "</option>");

                            });


                        });
            }


        });

    });
```

Controlelr:

```
    public function autocompleteCompanies(){
    $term = Input::get('term');

    $results = array();

    $queries = Companies::orderBy('name', 'asc')
        ->where('name', 'LIKE', $term.'%')
        ->take(5)->get();

    foreach ($queries as $query)
    {
        $results[] = [ 'id' => $query->id, 'value' => $query->name ];
    }
    return Response::json($results);
}

public function autocompleteCompanycities(){
    $term = Input::get('company_id');

    $cities = array();

    $company = Companies::findOrfail($term);

    $address = Addresses::with('cities')
             ->where('company_id', '=', $company->id)
             ->get();

    foreach($address as $addrs)
    {

        $cities[] = [ 'id' => $addrs->cities->id, 'name' => $addrs->cities->name];
    }
    return Response::json($cities);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need to reinitialize the select box with Materialize.css script, read [here](http://materializecss.com/forms.html) at the **Updating/Destroying Select** paragraph.

So try to do this operation.

```
$.get("/companies/autocompletecompanycities",
        {company_id: ui.item.id},
        function (data, status) {

            var model = $('#city_id');
            model.empty();
            $.each(data, function (index, element) {
                model.append("<option value='"+ element.id +"'>" + element.name + "</option>");

            });

            model.material_select(); //refresh the dropdown
});
```